# Error running pod install with swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I followed the instruction from Cocoapods.

Below is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.2'

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
pod 'SwiftSpinner', '~> 0.6'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
pod 'SuperRecord', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Toucan
```

When I did **pod install** I got the following error:

> Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.

Updated:

Below is my console log:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (1.1.4)
Installing SuperRecord (1.2)
Installing SwiftSpinner (0.6.0)
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.1.3)
Installing Toucan (0.2.0)
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni all of the libs listed above are all in Swift.

Comment: What is the pod version you are using, use "pod --version" to get it. Make sure you update Cocoapods installation to latest version using "sudo gem install cococapods".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add "use_frameworks!" to your Podfile because:

> Because Apple doesn't let you build static libraries that contain
> Swift. Unlike Objective-C, Apple doesn't ship the Swift standard
> runtime libraries with iOS. This decouples the language version from
> the platform version. When you build an app with Swift, you're
> responsible yourself to ship them. By default, Xcode uses
> swift-stdlib-tool to handle copying the Swift runtime dylibs, but the
> tooling falls short when attempting to ship frameworks that use Swift
> with an app that is Objective-C only. Your app executable and the
> frameworks you ship will all use the same set of dylibs, which are
> embedded into the Frameworks subdirectory of the application bundle.
>
> First, that's because you can't link against different versions of the
> standard libraries. Furthermore it is desirable to embed them only
> once and not multiple times, because of constraints to memory size and
> network speed, which are relevant for distribution.
> You can make CocoaPods integrate to your project via frameworks
> instead of static libraries by specifying use_frameworks!. If that's
> not present, you won't be able to integrate dependencies, if you
> depend on a pod which includes Swift source code.

Reference: http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/

Comment: Some of Pods are not working well with "use_frameworks!". So can you please guide how to deal with both pods together?

Answer (score 58):

Add "use_frameworks!" to your Podfile:

Please see below sample Podfile

```ruby
target 'MySample' do

  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'

  pod 'Net', '~> 0.2' #This is a sample in Swift

  use_frameworks! # <--Use this line
end
```

Comment: The comment flag in Ruby is "#" instead of "//".

Answer (score 9):

as it written in Podfile it says uncomment use_frameworks! is your are using Swift so all you have to do uncomment this line and all works just fine

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks! 

target 'YourProjectName' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1'
  pod 'SwiftSpinner', '~> 0.6'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
  pod 'SuperRecord', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'Toucan'
  # all other pods goes here 
end

target 'YourProjectName' do

end

target 'YourProjectName' do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple. You only have to add these lines to your pod file:

```ruby
target 'PassDTAFirebase' do

  inherit! :complete

    # Here your pods

  use_frameworks! 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I my case i used to upgrade cocoapods by command `sudo gem install cocoapods` and my issue got resolved. I used objective - c as well as swift libraries in my project.