# InstagramKit integration in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, instagram

As suggest title, I need to use `InstagramKit` (3.5.0) pod (written in objective-c) in a new swift project.

So I install pod (pod install), then I create my `InstagramSwift-Bridging-Header.h` and add-import library:

```
 #import <InstagramKit/InstagramEngine.h>
```

**Then, just building this empty project, I get:**

```
/Users/.../workspace/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift-Bridging-Header.h:5:9:
```

**note: in file included from**

```
/Users/.../workspace/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift-Bridging-Header.h:5: 
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                     ^ <unknown>:0:
```

**error: failed to import bridging header**

```
'/Users/.../workspace/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift-Bridging-Header.h'
```

**Expected a type    Failed to import bridging header**

```
'/Users/.../workspace/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift/InstagramSwift-Bridging-Header.h'
```

What could I miss?

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Closed Xcode, added `pod 'InstagramKit', '3.5.0'` to the Podfile, launched `pod install`, opened project in Xcode, added `import InstagramKit` and it's ok. Given your error, it looks like your `#import` statement in the header is wrong. Maybe a typo? Because I used `#import <InstagramKit/InstagramEngine.h>` too and it should work.

Comment: Is your bridging header properly declared in `Build Settings`?

Comment: Yep, it is.. I already follow your same steps, I can't figure out where is the mistake..

Comment: is already as you say, #import <InstagramKit/InstagramEngine.h> is in bridging header..

Comment: I re-try with an empty project again.. I add an image with project tree.

Comment: no way also restarting from a new project ):

Comment: There are any specific architecture setting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77627/discussion-between-eric-d-and-velthune).

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of discussions with @eric-d, I probably find the problem in my podfile that was:

```
target "InstagramSwift" do 

pod 'InstagramKit', '3.5.0' 

end
```

So I deleted project and start again from an empty project using Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0' 
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5' 
pod 'InstagramKit', '3.5.0'
```

Than I manually created SwitBridge.h and linked it in build settings.

Finally, in any swift file I can use instagramKit module, for example:

```
import InstagramKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let instagramEngine: InstagramEngine = InstagramEngine.sharedEngine()
    }

}
```

Probably, problem was that platform setting is missing.

## edit

Also,

```
"use_frameworks!"
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091522/error-running-pod-install-with-swift#answer-29091803).