# Issue installing pod written in Swift with CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to import the XLPagerTabStrip podfile to my project but I keep getting the error of:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Stripe (6.0.1)
Using XLPagerTabStrip (4.0.1)
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; 
        add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. 
        The Swift Pod being used is: XLPagerTabStrip`
```

Could you help me fix this issue? Here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'Stripe'
pod 'XLPagerTabStrip'

target 'Flokk' do

end

target 'FlokkTests' do

end
```

Comment: Error message is ``add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile`` ... that should give you a hint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error running pod install with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091522/error-running-pod-install-with-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `use_frameworks!` to the end of your Podfile like it tells you to