# "[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile to opt into using it

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have an existing project written in Objective C which contains private pods. I am writing a new private pod in swift language and need to integrate with existing objective C project as i have to go with Mix and Match approach. When I give "pod install" command i am getting below error

> "[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add
>   use_frameworks! to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The
>   Swift Pod being used is: XXXXXNetworkManagerSwift"

Here "XXXXXNetworkManagerSwift" is a new pod written in Swift language. It is a framework template.
Existing private pods are written using static lib templates.

My podfile is as below where i am using XXXXXNetworkManagerSwift as a dependency

Podfiile:-

```
source 'https://github.com/xxxx/ios-specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/cocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

target 'XXXXFoundationFramework' do
podspec :path => 'XXXFoundationFramework.podspec'
end
```

Comment: Put `use_frameworks!` at the top of the file.

Comment: i kept the same in my pod file. Thexn i am getting transitive dependency error  as below "[!] The 'Pods-XXX' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/xxxxxx/ModuleName/Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error running pod install with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091522/error-running-pod-install-with-swift)